# Delete all empty orders on user login

Tags: 7, commerce

**Case:** Delete all empty orders for a user when he/she login to the website.

We are using drupal commerce.

Please Help.

[image]

Comment: how empty order is placed can you described in detail?

Comment: I don't know, but when I see orders for some users, there are some orders with no line item. Attaching a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that these orders, where in the shopping cart when the current user log off, and never proceed to pay. In order to not lose this product in the cart for the next login, there has to be a relation to the user and product.

If your eCommerce module doesn't have any configuration to delete products on logout, try using hook_user_logout

> Note that when this hook is invoked, the changes have not yet been written to the database, because a database transaction is still in progress. The transaction is not finalized until the save operation is entirely completed and user_save() goes out of scope. You should not rely on data in the database at this time as it is not updated yet. You should also note that any write/update database queries executed from this hook are also not committed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use a module like [commerce_cart_expiration](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_expiration) which will automatically delete carts based on time criteria. The module also provides a default rule that can be configured via the Rules administration screen.

Edit:
Should also add that they are probably due to abandoned shopping sessions.
There is also another related module [Commerce Order Timeout](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/bpirkle/2577473) which may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following code to acheive the same. It may help others too.

```
/* Implements hook user login */

function module_name_user_login(&$edit, $account) {

//Get all order ids for current user.   
  $order_ids = db_select('commerce_order', 'o')
->fields('o', array('order_id'))
->condition('uid', $account->uid)
->execute()->fetchCol();

 if($order_ids >= 1){

  //Loop over order ids.
  foreach ($order_ids as $order_id) {

  //Load order  
  $order = commerce_order_load($order_id);

  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  //Get Order Total
  $total = $wrapper->commerce_order_total->amount->value();

  //If total is 0, Delete the order.
  if($total == 0){
      commerce_order_delete($order_id);
    }   
   }
  }
}
```